# Pasar horas miinutos y segundos a solo minutos con Date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hola tengo una api en donde me mandan asi el formato `00:25:00` y esto lo tengo que pasar a un formato que se vea bonito: asi 25:00 min
lo que habia echo yo es de esta forma

```
const date = new Date("00:25:00");
{format(date, "h:m ")}
```

pero me da error, y no se como pasar este formato `00:25:00` a minutos

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico en cuanto a lo que quieres exactamente? Por ejemplo, ¿qué pasa si tienes `"02:25:00"`? ¿Deberías mostrarlo como `"145:00"`? ¿Qué exactamente estás buscando, ocultar los segundos, ocultar las horas, convertir las horas a minutos, mostrar la fecha así solo cuando la hora sea 0? No queda clara tu pregunta. Sin contar de que con javascript no puedes crear un objeto `Date` con solo la hora. Utiliza [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar una librería externa, como **moment** o **luxon**.

Pero en caso de que prefieras evitarlos, podrías hacer algo así:

```
const getDateOutput = (date) => {
  const [h, m, s] = date.split(':').map(val => +val);
  const hLabel = h === 1 ? 'hour' : 'hours';
  const mLabel = m === 1 ? 'min' : 'minutes';
  const sLabel = s === 1 ? 'sec' : 'seconds';


  return `${h} ${hLabel} ${m} ${mLabel} ${s} ${sLabel}`
}

getDateOutput('00:25:00'); // Output: "0 hours 25 minutes 0 seconds"
getDateOutput('10:30:20'); // Output: "10 hours 30 minutes 20 seconds"
getDateOutput('00:00:14'); // Output: "0 hours 0 minutes 14 seconds"
```